# Azure API Management new dev portal - how to add a new administrator

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

There is a step by step configuration to add API Management Administrators and then use a Powershell command to retrieve a URL to open the Developer portal as an administrator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-administrators-group).
But unfortunately, it is not working with the new developer portal, only with the legacy portal.

What are the steps to use with the new developer portal?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more involved.

1. Generate yourself a token using this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/user/getsharedaccesstoken
2. Get service details using this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apimanagementservice/get to see if new dev portal has been assigned custom hostname. Can skip it if you already have this information from somewhere else.
3. You redirect URL will be: https://[hostname]/signin-sso?token=[token]

Comment: Unfortunately also does not seem to work for the new portal. I get redirected to the legacy portal and user didn't change groups